# adding google APIs library to cmake build

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to create CMake build to compile my project with google APIs library, the source of google APIs is generated with protocol buffers.

let's say I want to make CMake file for https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe.cc

streaming_transcribe.cc is using 
`#include "google/cloud/speech/v1beta1/cloud_speech.grpc.pb.h"` which is located in the source directory of google APIs and its source is needed to be compiled and linked against the grpc library and grpc++ and a bunch of other sources in the same directory.

the makefile in the samples https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/

is compiling the sources in the google APIs directory to object files without linking them to grpc, and then is archived to ar file and just then the streaming_transcribe.cc is compiled and linked with ar file and grpc.

how can I make the same process for cmake file build?

Comment: I guess archive of object files is just a *static library*. In CMake you can create it with [add_library(STATIC)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_library.html) command.

Comment: then I can't compile the sources on another platform

Comment: Which error do you get on another platform? Which `CMakeLists.txt` file do you use?

Comment: I meant other architectures, I can't compile google APIs sources on my PC and put it on ARM architecture and compile the project there so I want that the CMake do it.

Comment: Original `Makefile` **compiles** sources into objects before placing them into archive. *Compilation process* is always *architecture-dependent*, so you cannot reuse object files (or archive of them) on other architecture. In other words, it is not a problem of CMake, but it is a constraint of original `Makefile`.

Comment: I know that I can't reuse object files, what I'm asking is how can I make the same process in CMake like this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/Makefile make file do. how can I make CMake compile all the sources in one directory and archive it to ar file

Comment: Again, in the Makefile you refer to [this rule](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/Makefile#L34): `googleapis.ar: $(GOOGLEAPIS_CCS:.cc=.o)` archives **objects**, not *sources*. So I am not sure which functionality of the Makefile you want to emulate in CMake. BTW, in you question post you talk about **archiving object files** too. Please, add to the question post **exact code** (from Makefile), which you want to achive with CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev first off all thank you for trying to help me with that. what I am trying to achieve is compiling source files and archiving them to ar file and then include the archive in my source files compilation. something like "1. compile google api source files 2.archive them to ar file 3.target_link_libraries(project_name googleapis)"

Comment: 1,2. `add_library(googleapis STATIC <sources>)` 3. `target_link_libraries(<project_name> googleapis)`. If you want to compile sources on one architecture for run them on other architecture, this is known as *cross-compiling*, and it is a different question.

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev, can you add an answer so I can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive of object files is a *static* library. With CMake you may create it with:

```
add_library(<library-name> STATIC <sources...>)
```